How do I become a peer reveiver in a journal
I have masters and have been working for 5 years. I have 1 paper published where I am in the list of contributors, basically not the first or second author.
I have 2 other papers in the process where I am first author.
I am planning on writing a review article also.
I want to become a peer reveiver. How do I achieve that? Also are Master's considered for it?

What field are you in? And why do you want to be a reviewer? What is your larger professional goal in doing so?

I am in the Field of cardiac regeneration research. I want to contribute to the community and also keep myself updated with all the new research that is taking place in the field. Also I want to build my profile so in future I can apply for grants and have my own lab.
